# Mobile app with data from TYPO3

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, typo3

I don't know anything about TYPO3.
I have a potential client who pushes content on a website through TYPO3 and now wants to expose some of this content in a mobile application I'm supposed to develop.
I use to implement mobile apps with Ionic.

So I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to read TYPO3 content as a web service so I can call it in my Ionic app ?

2) Is TYPO3 able to expose some part of his content in a responsive website so I just have to configure it and show that website in my webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TYPO3 you can configure any kind of output. That can be the same content in the same structure as the original website.
You can configure additional pagetypes.

```
jsonPage = PAGE
jsonPage {
    typeNum = 1234
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        :
    }
    :
}
```

Often this is done for a print-view or a pure text view without tags.

In this way you can output the page content as e.g. JSon or XML.
I even did an output once as PHP includes which had the pagecontent in php-variables.

So you can request abstract data, or the same data with another rendering than the *normal* page like a special responsive rendering.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer, I feel it's the way to go I will ask them if they can add a new json rendering for this specific content I am interested with, at a different port if possible then I can work it

Comment: Simply tell them to add a new typenum.
It is quite easy to do so by adding 

mynewpagename = PAGE
mynewpagename.typeNum = 123

You can then access this one using &typenum=123 at the end of your url.

Additional to that, you could disable all Header and stuff.

Comment: Please consider to mark the question as answered if it's solved now. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not want to use TYPO3 at all, you can still make your own queries using php/mysql as all content and page related data (at least should be)is stored in the database and is well sorted there.
(Which is much more work than defining a new pagetype as mentionned above - but could also be an option)

Comment: Then he might need some more understanding of TYPO3 as TYPO3 uses a lot of fields which control visibility (it's not only deleted and hidden, but starttime, endtime, language and workspaces). And plugins (`simple` contentelements on a page) could show records from other pages with additional logic. All that might be needed to be reflected in the `simple` query. In this way he needed to be more TYPO3 expert than doing a new rendering (or order a special rendering from the TYPO3 administrator)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know TYPO3 was backed up by MySql and PHP that's an interesting option too